# electronjs electron-forge please install sqlite3 package manually

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-forge

I'm trying to make an Electron app that uses a sqlite3 database locally.

I followed the instructions and set up a template using this link https://www.electronforge.io/templates/typescript-+-webpack-template

I also installed sequelize and sqlite3

```
npm i --save sequelize sqlite3
```

I packaged the app with

```
electron-forge make
```

When I run the app, I got an error message as follow
[image]

I tried adding

```
externals: ["sqlite3"]
```

to the file **webpack.main.config.ts** but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by passing sqlite3 as dialectModule, which forced electron forge to package the native module.

```
import sqlite3 from 'sqlite3';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    "database",
    'user',
    'password',
    {
      dialect: "sqlite",
      dialectModule: sqlite3
    }
  );
  
export default sequelize;
```